# React-Native custom Text component with Typescript : "Conversion of type React.ReactNode to type Text..."

Tags: typescript, react-native, components

I've been trying to implement the following custom **Text** component in React Native.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text as RNText, TextStyle } from 'react-native';

export interface TextProps {
  children: React.ReactNode; 
  type?: 'title' | 'large' | 'medium' | 'small';
  weight?: 'thin' | 'light' | 'regular' | 'bold';
  color?: string;
  style?: TextStyle;
};

const Text = ({
  children,
  type,
  weight,
  color,
  style = {}
}: TextProps) => {
  const fontSize = () => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'title':
        return 24;
      case 'large':
        return 28;
      case 'medium':
        return 18;
      case 'small':
        return 14;

      default:
        return 16;
    }
  };

  const fontFamily = () => {
    switch (weight) {
      case 'thin':
        return 'Lato-Thin';
      case 'light':
        return 'Lato-Light';
      case 'regular':
        return 'Lato-Regular';
      case 'bold':
        return 'Lato-Bold';

      default:
        return 'Lato-Regular';
    }
  };

  return (
    <RNText 
      style={{
        fontFamily, 
        fontWeight, 
        color: color || '#fff', 
        {...style}
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </RNText>
  );
};

export default Text;
```

However, I have an error on **<RNText>** : *"Type {} is missing the following properties from type 'Text': measure, measureInWindow, measureLayout, setNativeProps and 9 more"*

If i remove the style props of the **<RNText>** component, I've got another error in VSCode: *"Conversion of type {children: React.ReactNode} to type Text may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If it was intentional, convert the expression to unknown first"*

Seems like I would have the set the wrong type for the children props ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Change the children type in TextProps to:

```
children: (string | Element)[] | string | string[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TextProps` type.

```
 import { Text as RNText, TextStyle,TextProps } from 'react-native';
```

Since you are using interface, merge it with `TextProps`

```
export interface TextProps extends TextProps {
  children: React.ReactNode; 
  type?: 'title' | 'large' | 'medium' | 'small';
  weight?: 'thin' | 'light' | 'regular' | 'bold';
  color?: string;
  style?: TextStyle;
};
```

Also return type should be ReactElement

```
const Text = ({
  children,
  type,
  weight,
  color,
  style = {}
}: TextProps):ReactElement => {
```